# winforms listbox items to business layer

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to pass my listbox items down to my business layer.

```
//From Save click event
var toBusiness = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in lbProducts.Items)
{
    toBusiness.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

Is this the way to do it?

Comment: A better way to do it is to Bind controls to objects in your business layer. eg  `lbProducts.Datasource = toBusiness;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would thing that the items came from the business layer, correct? So you just need to pass something to the business layer that is non-gui that allows the business layer to recognise them. If your item has a unique ID then you could just pass a List or array of the unique ID, otherwise just pass an array of the items.

```
var items = lbProducts.Items.OfType<MyItemType>().ToArray()
myBusinessLayer.DoSomething(items);
```

or

```
var ids = lbProducts.Items.OfType<MyItemType>().Select(i => i.ID).ToArray()
myBusinessLayer.DoSomething(ids);
```